# Why git keep giving me 'hello' when i ran git commit. And my staged file wasn't committed

Tags: git

Yesterday I created a git repository. My repository folder looks like:

[image: repo contents]

I ran `git add -A`, after that I ran `git status`. As you can see, my file is staged successfully. However when i ran `commit -m 'first commit'`. It kept giving me this message:

[image: git commit message]
And my staged file hadn't been commited. Some ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `ls -lF .git/hooks` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. a list of shell commands starting with `git init`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt seems like he already has.  冯洋洲, please put the result of these commands in your question: `echo $SHELL`, `git --version`, `git config --list`    Take out any private information before you do.

Comment: Sorry, but where? I don't see anything in the question. The reason I'm raising this topic is because "created a git repository" is an intended result. What OP actually did is a different question!

Comment: It is a pre-commit hook in my .git/hooks which just print hello and exit 1. I remembered that I added a global hook last time and it is created every time i run git init as a git template. Thanks for giving some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have installed a pre-commit hook that:

1. prints `hello`
2. exits nonzero, so as to prevent the commit.

That would produce the behavior you see.  To fix it, remove or fix the pre-commit hook.  Look at `.git/hooks/` and check your configuration for a `core.hooksPath` setting:

```
git config --get core.hooksPath
```

If the latter produces output, check that directory for a pre-commit hook.

Comment: you are right!!! It is a pre-commit hook in my .git/hooks which just print hello and exit 1.  I remembered that I added a global hook last time and it is created every time i run git init as a git template. Really thank you.